# Micronaut HttpClient: Correct way to handle spaces in URIs

Tags: micronaut

I am using micronaut 1.0.3 with Java8. I am trying to understand when and how encoding is required for HttpClient.

First Problem:

When I use HttpClient with spaces in the URI, I get an error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 6: /bleah bleah

Question: Do I need to encode the URIs? I expect HttpClient to do this for me.

Second Problem:

I try to encode using Java's URLEncoder, which converts the space to a +. This doesn't match the end-point on the server. I get the following on the server:

```
18:26:02.261 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-9] DEBUG i.m.h.server.netty.NettyHttpServer - Server localhost:8081 Received Request: GET /bleah+bleah
18:26:02.261 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-9] DEBUG i.m.h.s.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler - Matching route GET - /bleah+bleah
18:26:02.262 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-9] DEBUG i.m.h.s.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler - No matching route found for URI /bleah+bleah and method GET
18:26:02.262 [nioEventLoopGroup-1-9] DEBUG i.m.h.s.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler - Encoding emitted response object [Page Not Found] using codec: io.micronaut.jackson.codec.JsonMediaTypeCodec@4a8b5227
```

If I encode the spaces using %20, all works well.

Question: Why does the URL not match? What is the correct way to encode the URL?

Sample project at https://github.com/gboersma/http-client-encoding-issue.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that URIs do need to be encoded. There is a utility class `UriBuilder` which is used to generate encoded URLs. In this case, the correct way to use it is something like `UriBuilder.of("/{parameter}”).expand(parameter, ‘bleah bleah’).toString()`.

Thanks to Sergio del Amo for clarifing this one.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly Answer your first question:Of course you should encode the space in the URL,but the HttpClient will not help you automatically,you can use java's method of replace to replace the space;
As for secondly,I don't know the true reason,but use the %20 replace the space is a customary operation,just like use the %23 replace the '#',it's not necessary to get to the bottom of a matter

Comment: You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54282890/edit) the answer to make it looks better, it uses `markdown`, and also those buttons on the editor will help you.

Comment: Notably, please put spaces after punctuation such as commas and colons; that will make your text easier to read. You can also mark up code references with `backticks`.